# Hybrid-Analysis.com indicates the website that my macOS system is contacting is likely malicious

Tags: malware, macos, web-service, filtering

Backstory:
I just upgraded my MacBook from OS X 10.11.6 to the most updated version of macOS, 10.14.6 Mojave. I also have the Little Snitch network filter installed. I know nearly nothing about information security, so when I see my computer connecting to a website in another country for reasons I can't determine, I get a little paranoid.

For example, my network filter is showing me that my computer is contacting a particular website `adriver.ru`, and it's being contacted by a built-in system file: `/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc`

I did a google search and Hybrid-Analysis says that this is a potentially malicious website... https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/aeb562d94494fd967c0ef064f528956192bcff8b00033c0f9892d7cafeda174e?environmentId=120

**How should I interpret:**

1. Every strange connection my macOS computer makes?
2. Hybrid-Analysis.com telling me my built-in macOS software is contacting a malicious website?

Could it be that a legitimate, built-in process on macOS Mojave has been hacked?

**Am I overreacting?**

Comment: "my built-in macOS software is contacting " That is not what you are being told. A component used by **Safari**, the browser, is contacting some website, which, for a browser, is not really surprising. So you will need to have a look at your Safari, the websites you opened there, your extensions, etc...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I wasn't using Safari. It appeared to happen on its own.